# isLoading without setState? Flutter (CircularProgressIndicator)

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I tried

```
setState(() {isLoading = true})
//do something
setState(() {isLoading = false})
```

in the onTab(){}

but with setState the data like pdfFile and pdfController gets overridden and the app is not pushing to a new route.

Well, my question is: How to show a loading animation to user and if the loading stuff is finished, push to the screen with the downloaded data? Maybe I need something without setState? What possibilities we have?

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: firebase.base
            .collection('xxx')
            .doc(firebase.auth.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection("xxx")
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {

            final liste = snapshot.data!.docs;
               return Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    itemCount: liste.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      Map data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map;
                     String fileName = data['fileName'];
                     String url = data['url'];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          http.Response pdfFile =
                              await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

                          final pdfController = PdfController(
                              document:
                                  PdfDocument.openData(pdfFile.bodyBytes));

                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      PdfViewScreen(pdfController, fileName)));
                        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the follow logic works for you:

`onTap` only redirects the user to PdfViewScreen. In PdfViewScreen you use a FutureBuilder to resolve `http.get(Uri.parse(url))` after which the FutureBuilder will return the PDFviewer that you use. In the FutureBuilder you can then show a progressIndicator

Comment: Half of this is working. I used a `FutureBuilder` to get the pdf. The `CircularProgressIndicator` is working, then it will push to the PdfViewScreen but I can't press the back button and getting some errors.

Comment: Perhaps you can upload your new code, might be able to help again

Comment: I try to use the code in other screens too but I think the showDialog thing is not the right way to reuse it in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `else` expression after curly bracket. Or use only `return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());` after `if`

Answer (score 0):

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: firebase.base
            .collection('xxx')
            .doc(firebase.auth.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection("xxx")
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final liste = snapshot.data!.docs;
            return Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    itemCount: liste.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      Map data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map;
                      String fileName = data['fileName'];
                      String url = data['url'];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          Future<http.Response> pdfFile =
                              http.get(Uri.parse(url));
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return FutureBuilder<http.Response>(
                                    future: http.get(Uri.parse(url)),
                                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                        final pdfController = PdfController(
                                            document: PdfDocument.openData(
                                                snapshot.data!.bodyBytes));

                                        return PdfViewScreen(
                                            pdfController, fileName);
                                      }
                                      return const Center(
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                    });
                              });
                        },
```

Comment: Interesting way of putting everything together. My idea was actually that you would use the Screen with the StreamBuilder (the StreamBuilder that you use to request the list with url's to pdf files) and in an onTap event you navigate the user to the PdfViewScreen. In the PdfViewScreen you can than start with a FutureBuilder to load the pdfFile

Comment: @BJW
In the PdfScreen is already a loading widget from the plugin :)